# How to sort string number in descending order in AGgrid

Tags: javascript, sorting

Im having aolumn in AGgrid where I need it to be displayed as thousands separated.
Example : 1200150 should be displayed as 1,200,150. I could achieve this using below "(parseFloat(e.volume).toLocaleString("en-US"))".

But I want to sort the AG grid rows in descending order based on **volume **column. it is taking it as string and sorting is not done in a proper way. Sorting is done based on the string something like **9,999,999** ,**99**,999,999 88,888, 888, **8,908,777**, ...etc

How can I sort this kind of column in the AG grid and display ? I also tried using custom sort but no luck.
Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

I also tried using custom sort but no luck.